# Images are off-centered for mobile browsing

Tags: html, css, mobile, position

Ive made a few websites, but for some reason my newest webpage is rendering incorrectly on mobile browsers. I have a feeling it has to do with the units I'm using for spacing (pixels), but I'm unsure.

The web-page is www.zfisch.com

Here are some snippets of relevant code, first, the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
```

Next, the CSS I have in place for the images:

```
a #twitter {
    background-color: black;
    height: 32px;
    width: 110px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 46%;
    top: 159px;
    z-index: 1;
}


a #email {
    background-color: black;
    height: 32px;
    width: 110px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 46%;
    top: 159px;
    z-index: 1;
}

img[src="zack.jpg"] {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
    margin-top: 100px;
    left: 44.5%;
    position: absolute;

}

p[id="brackets"] {
    font-size: 100px;
    left: 43%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;


}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: The images near the bottom?

Comment: Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I just took a look at it and for the bracket at the bottom do `text-align: center`. And the images are possibly margin issues. I also think the `left` is knocking something off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute position is not the best way to go about that, but if you want to stick with it try a setup like this:

```
img[src="zack.jpg"] {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
```

For the other elements, do the same (pulling them left half their width) and make sure a width is set.

Otherwise, remove positioning and set the container to `text-align: center` to center the image.